# preserving Agnihotra in present days?

Tags: vedas, yajna, agni

I have heard in olden days, People used to preserve the Agni used in marriage ritual and the same agni was used for cremation of the same pair wedded. My question is, how this Agni was preserved and can it be followed in present days?

Comment: what do u mean ? the same aupasana agni method is used by agnihotris even today. although the number of people is extremely low.

Comment: @mar looking for that method alone.

Comment: i'm just saying that there is no difference between 'present day' method and 'olden day' method.. so your question could just be preserving Agnihotra. Also, unlikely to get answer on internet, have to go to ashram or math to find out.

Comment: @mar ok edited. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I remember that it is present in Ramayana, when viswamitra is taking Rama and Lakshmana to forest.

Comment: @hanugm cool! see if you could find it an post an answer.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Okay...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main fire in the house of one observing the fire rites, was inherited from his father's garhapaytya fire. The derivative fires the ahavaniya and dakshinagni could be lighted from this or from the arani fire-sticks ritual.

Quote:-
Gārhapatya (गार्हपत्य).—[gṛhapatinā nityaṃ saṃyuktaḥ, saṃjñāyāṃ ñya]

1. One of the three sacred fires perpetually maintained by a householder, which he receives from his father and transmits to his descendants, and from which fires for sacrificial purposes are lighted; अथ हैनं गार्हपत्योऽनु- शशास (atha hainaṃ gārhapatyo'nu- śaśāsa) Ch. Up.4.11.1; cf. Manusmṛti 2.231.
2. The place where this sacred fire is kept.

-tyam The government of a family; position and dignity of a householder; गार्हपत्येन सन्त्य ऋतुना यज्ञनीरसि (gārhapatyena santya ṛtunā yajñanīrasi) Ṛgveda 1.15.12.
Derivable forms: gārhapatyaḥ (गार्हपत्यः).

Of the places I have heard, the last fire in Nepal near Bhaktapur extinguished the fire, because the old agnihotri could not pay for the fuel after Nepal govt. discontinued help after becoming a democracy.

Of the household fires in India, I am only acquainted with the fire of the so entitled Akkithiripad surnames Namputhiris of Kerala who participated in the Atiratras eg at Panjal.( attended by the learned Profs Michael Witzel, Asko Parpola and others from time to time.

The following is from the kanchi sankaracharyas website and offers surrounding info and background:-

Four hundred yajnas or sacrifices are said to be mentioned in the Vedas. Of these, aupasana alone is to be performed by all the four varnas. Though the first three varnas have the right to all the other sacrifices, in practice these were performed mostly by Brahmins and Ksatriyas only. But later Ksatriyas too neglected to perform them. There are yajnas to be conducted specially by them to earn physical strength, victory in war, and so on. Sacrifices like rajasuya and asvamedha were performed by imperial rulers. They are yagas that have to be performed by Vaisyas for a good agriculture yield, for wealth, etc. As mentioned before, the yajamana of a sacrifice may be a Ksatriya or a Vaisya but the four priests must be Brahmins. (The idea behind it is that if members of these two castes were to participate directly in the sacrifices their duties like protecting the country and looking after agriculture would suffer.)

Not all sacrifices need be performed by all Brahmins. A number of them are meant to serve one specific purpose or another. For instance, you must have heard of the putrakamesti in the Ramayana, the sacrifice performed to beget a son.

Any rite meant to fulfil a wish is "kamya-karma" and it comes under the optional category. Then these are rites that are obligatory on your part to conduct for the good of your Atman as well as of the world. They come under the category of "nitya-karma", but the word "nitya" here does not denote "daily".

In the category of nitya-karma there are 21 sacrifices. There is no compulsion with regard to the rest of the 400. But the 21, included in the forty samskaras, must be performed at least once in a life time. As we have seen, these are divided into groups of seven - pakayajnas, haviryajnas and somyajnas.

Marriage is conducted with offerings made in the fire, is it not? Aupasana, which must be performed every day, is commenced in this fire and it must be preserved throughout one's life. The seven pakayajnas, rites like upanayana and sraddha must be conducted in the aupasana fire. The son lights his aupasana fire during his marriage from his father's aupasana fire. The son's aupasana fire, like his father's must be maintained throughout his life. Thus, without any break, the sacred fire is kept burning in the family generation after generation.

All rites in which the aupasana fire is used and pertain to an individual and his family are "Grhyakarmas". The seven pakayajnas also belong to this category. They are related exclusively to the family and are not very elaborate. Even so they are conductive to the good of the world outside also. Grhyasutras deal with such rites. They belong to the Smritis and are called "Smarta-karmas".

The elaborate works that are especially meant for the well-being of mankind are called "Srautakarmas". They are so called because their procedure is directly based on the authority of Sruti or the Vedas. The sastras dealing with them are "Srautasutras".

I told you, do you remember, that there was no question of Sruti being superior to Smrti or vice versa? Similarly, the Srautasutras and the Grhyasutras are of equal importance. In the sanatana dharma that goes under the name of Hinduism both are to be cared for like our two eyes.

The aupasana fire (lighted at the time of marriage from that of the groom's father) is divided into two in a ceremony called "agniyadhana". One part is called "grhyagni" or "smartagni": it is meant for rites to be performed at home. The second part is srautagni and meant for srauta rites. These two sacred fires must be preserved throughout.

Grhyagni is also called aupasanagni since the daily rite of aupasana is performed in it. This is the fire contained in one "kunda" and so it is called "ekagni". Rites conducted in the family are included in the chapter called "Ekagni-kanda" in the Apastamba-sutra. The samskaras and other rites I have so far mentioned are mostly in accordance with this work since the majority of Brahmins in the South are Krsna-Yajurvedins following this sutra. Rigvedins and Samavedins who constitute a minority follow the Asvalayana and Gobhila-sutras respectively. These differences, however, relate only to the rites performed at home. There are no differences in the srauta rites with regard to the different Vedas.

Srautagni meant for the srauta rites is in the form of three fires burning in three mounds. So it is called tretagni. The section in the Apastamba-sutra dealing with rites performed in it is called "Tretagni-kanda". One who worships the three Agnis is called a "tretagni" or "srautin" and, if he worships the srauta and grhya fires, he is called an "ahitagnin". One who performs an elaborate sacrifice like a somayajna is called a "yajva", "diksita" or "makhin". And one who conducts the greatest of the somayajnas, vajapeya, is known as a "vajapeyin". Sacrifices are called variously "kratu", "makha", "isti", "stoma", "samsta". There are some difference between these. Ancient Tamil works contain references to "mutti" (tretagni or srautagni).

One of the three sacred fires, one of the tretagni, is called "garhapatya" and it belongs to the master of the household. It must be kept burning in the garhapatya mound which is circular in shape. In this no oblations are to be made directly. Fire must be taken from it and tended in another mound for the performance of rites relating to the fathers (this is different from the usual sraddha and is ritual performed to the manes every new moon) and also for certain deities. This mound is in the south, so it is called "daksinagni" and it is semicircular in shape. Offerings to deities are made generally in a third fire in the east called "ahavaniya" and it is also to kindled from the garhapatya fire. In the North any yaga or sacrificial rite is called a "havan", the word being derived from "ahavaniya". The ahavaniya mound is square in shape. Big sacrifices like somayajnas and other meant to propitiate deities are to be conducted in the fire taken from the ahavaniya mound to the yagnasala or the hall where a sacrifice is held.

If aupasana is a grhyakarma, agnihotra is a srauta ceremony and it too must be performed twice a day. Agniyadhana mentioned before and agnihotra are the first two of the seven haviryajnas. Those who perform agnihotra are called agnihotrins. (Nowadays smoking is referred to as agnihotra and going to the races as asvamedha. Such references are intended to be humorous but are indeed blasphemous.)

If the agnihotra fire is extinguished for whatever reason, it must be kindled again through a new adhana (agniyadhana) ceremony. The same applies to the aupasana fire. Now in the majority of houses neither the aupasana nor the agnihotra fire burns. I have mentioned here how these fires can be renewed since most of you perhaps must not have kept them after your marriage.

In aupasana unbroken rice grains are offered in the fire and in agnihotra milk, ghee or unbroken rice grains. (It has become customary now to offer milk in the agnihotra. )

As already mentioned, the daksinagni and the ahavaniyagni are made from the garhapatyagni. When srauta rites for the fathers have been performed in the daksinagni and other srauta rites in the ahavaniyagni, the two fires no longer have the exalted name of "srautagni" and are just like any other ordinary fire and they have to be extinguished. Only the garhapatya and aupasana fires are to be kept burning throughout.

Comment: What are ahavaniya and dakshinagni ?

Comment: They are the remaining two fires if the fires of sacrifice given to Nachiketas by Yama are 3. Some hold them to be 5 fires but that is a rarity. The Ahavaniya is used for important sacrifices for which  fire is taken from it and the Dakshinagni is to protect the south or threats from nether regions. Also used for curative purposes.

Comment: Could you please join main chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism ?